# Is there a method in ReactJS like FindOrCreate

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code:

```
async _addStructure() {
        const {pmo} = this.state;
        let struct = null;
        try {
            struct = await structureService.getWhere({
                name: pmo
            })
        } catch (e) {
            return null
        }

        if (struct.length) {
            return struct[0]
        }
        try {
            const structure = await structureService.create(new Structure(pmo));
            toastr.success('Succès', 'succès');
            return structure

        } catch (e) {
            return null
        }
    }
```

That get a structure, and if null, create a new one.

Is there any existing method in ReactJS that can handle it. In NodeJS, it seems that we could do:

```
        return Structure.findOrCreate({where: {name: pmo}}, {
            "name": pmo,

        })
```

which is much cleaner.

I can't find anything on the internet, which probably means it is not possible, just looking for a confirmation!

Comment: Why don't you just implement it in structureService if you need it on the client?

Comment: Yes, it would be a possibility, but just checking before implementing myself, if  there is not any similar functionality in React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to "get a structure, and if null, create a new one."

Looks like [`lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) which goes well with [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get)

```
// API
_.set(object, path, value)

const object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
// => 4

_.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```

> Sets the value at path of object. If a portion of path doesn't exist, it's created.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say that what I want is to FindOrCreate an object in a MongoDB, not just a variable. I guess it is what lodash does, does it ?

Comment: You really should do it on the server-side, how creating an object in Mongo related to React? Send a request to a service to handle it. Lodash is utils library for javascript.